# Create column headers in Excel after every 3 Columns using java, Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, for-loop, apache-poi

I'm trying to create an excel sheet wherein I'm getting all the Header values from an ArrayList and looping it to print the headers after every 3 cells.
This is my code.

```
    for (int x = 4; x < projectLocationList.size(); x++) {
        columnHeaderCell = regionList.createCell(x+3);
        columnHeaderCell.setCellValue(projectLocationList.get(x-3));
        columnHeaderCell.setCellStyle(columnHeaderStyle);
    }
```

For `x=4` because I have to print column from 7th cell. The problem I'm facing is I'm getting only the last three values. Please help me fix this for loop.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

initialize for loop from 0 only and take a different variable outside the for loop for creating cell number.

```
static int cellNum = 7;
for (int x = 0; x < projectLocationList.size(); x++) {
    columnHeaderCell = regionList.createCell(cellNum);
    columnHeaderCell.setCellValue(projectLocationList.get(x));
    columnHeaderCell.setCellStyle(columnHeaderStyle);
cellNum = cellNum + 3;
}
```